# What role is required to create an iOS distribution certificate?

Tags: iphone, ios, roles, admin, agent

In writing this question, I figured out that the [Agent role is required to create an iOS distribution certificate](https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/). I'm working with a partner. He created an Apple ID for the corporation to use for enrolling into the iOS Developer Program, and he added me as an Admin. He is the business contact. I am the developer. How can I get the Agent role also so that I can submit the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there's only one Agent per Apple ID. I have a similar situation with a partner - and we have had to share same login in order for me to create Ad Hoc distribution profiles, etc.

If there is a better way, I'd love to hear about it ;-)

Comment: Yeo, that's what we ended up doing as well. Would be nice if you could have more than one person who could make distribution certificates & provisions and submit the app, etc.